# Gradle with Java11 build produces intermittent compilation errors

Tags: docker, gradle, java-11

We are using **gradle:6.9.1-jdk11-hotspot** image to build one of our java jar components.

### Gradle 6.9.1

Build time:   2021-08-20 11:15:18 UTC.
Revision:     f0ddb54aaae0e44f0a7209c3c0274d506ea742a0
Kotlin:       1.4.20
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          11.0.11 (AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.11+9)
OS:           Linux 5.10.47-linuxkit amd64.

The Gradle build file also use `io.freefair.aspectj.compile-time-weaving:3.8.4` for compile time weaving.

We get the following compilation errors

**The type javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader is not accessible.

import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;**

**The type javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory is not accessible

import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;**

**XMLEventReader cannot be resolved to a type

private XMLEventReader xmlEventReader;**

**XMLInputFactory cannot be resolved

XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();**

This compilation error does not happen consistently and it happens intermittently. Retrying after a couple of times the build succeeds.

We use docker-compose of version 2.0.1 to build the image. The Gradle build is executed as part of building the docker image.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM gradle:6.9.1-jdk11-hotspot

ENV GRADLE_USER_HOME=/app/.gradle
USER root

WORKDIR app/libs
COPY common/*.gradle ./common/
COPY common/src ./common/src

RUN gradle --stacktrace  --no-daemon :common:build
```

Comment: Also posted here: https://coderanch.com/t/747901/java/Gradle-Java-build-produces-intermittent

Comment: Which compiler do you use? We have a similar problem, and it seems to be related to the Groovy compiler.